# Reutilize create form for update functionality

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In a college project we're developing an average CRUD application, we're being told to create a Create form and a Update form that are identical save that the Update one loads with data of an object that selected on a list beforehand, besides both forms are exactly the same.

Wouldn't it be more efficient to just use the same Create form?

I was thinking in something like adding a boolean to the form constructor, true for create and false for update, but I don't know if this is good practice.

Something like this:

```
public partial class frmLocal
{  
     private bool isCreate;
     private int  objId;

     public frmLocal(boolean _isCreate, int _id = 0)
     {
          InitializeComponent();
          isCreate = _isCreate;
          objId = _id;
     } 

     private void frmLocal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
     {
          if(isCreate)
          {
               try 
               {    
                    //Shows blank create form  
               } 
               catch (Exception ex) 
               {    
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error.");    
               }
          }
          else
          {
               //Loads an object's data with some stored procedure
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a better practice to create a public property and set the value before create the instance of the new form.

So in your form you will have:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public bool IsCreate { get; set; }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsCreate)
        {
            //load specific controls/data for creating
        }
        else
        {
            //load specific controls/data for updating
        }
    }
}
```

And supposing you have a Form1 to open the Form2, you will use:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var formCreateUpdate = new Form2 {IsCreate = true};
        formCreateUpdate.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually looks pretty legit!